# I cant navigate to next page in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOMwD.png)
the next and skip buttons are not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjxfS.png)

Is anyone knows what the issue?

Comment: can you share the code of your button

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your button in a GestureDetector widget and for the onTap: property specify to go your next screen (using page route or navigator).

Answer (score 0):

you can use GestureDetector or Inkwell onTap property and can use this func

```
 Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => nextPage(
                              // next page variable if have
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
```